# How do you access an asp.net code behind session object member variable in javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a class that handles all of my session variables in my asp.net application. Moreover, I sometimes store objects in the session variables so as to allow me to code very similar to a normal .net application.

For example, here is an object in a session variable:

```
public cUser User
{
    get { return (cUser)HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentUser"]; }
    set { HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentUser"] = value; }
}
```

And here is the instance of MySessionClass:

```
    public static MySessinClass Current
    {
        get
        {
            MySessionClass session = (MySessionClass)HttpContext.Current.Session["MySessionClass"];
            if (session == null) {
                session = new MySessionClass();
                HttpContext.Current.Session["MySessionClass"] = session;
            }
            return session;
        }
    }
```

So, in my code behind aspx page, I would just do something such as

```
int userID = MySessionClass.Current.User.UserID;
```

This works great and I love it. However, I want to apply the same principle in javascript from my aspx page:

```
var userID = <%=MySessionClass.Current.User.UserID%>;
```

However, when I access that webpage, I get an error saying that it does not recognize the MySessionClass object.

So, given the context that I am in, what would be the best way to reference that UserID variable, from the object, from the session, in javascript? Maybe my syntax to reference it is off or I am going at it the wrong way. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've defined it as a static member, you would need to qualify your reference with the page type:

```
var userID = <%=MyPageType.MySessionClass.Current.User.UserID%>;
```

That should be enough.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by page type. The "MySessionClass" is not a page, but a simple MySessionClass.cs file. It uses the HttpContext.Current.Session to access the session variables

Comment: +1 The page type is on top of your `.aspx.cs` file, f.e. `public partial class YourPageType : Page`.  If your `MySessionClass` is in a different file, specify it's namespace, f.e. `<%= MyNamespace.MySessionClass.Current.User.UserID%>`

Comment: How are we meant to know that? Please publish all relevant code then. From your current example, I don't know if Current is a member on your page or this static session class. Additionally, do you have the right namespaces imported in your ASPX page directivecs?